# Java - Getting the URL's parameter

Tags: java, url, parameters, playframework-2.0

I have a URL something like this

I'm using play framework

HTTP Routes:

```
GET     /students                    controllers.Application.Get()
POST    /students                    controllers.Application.Post()
PUT     /students/{studentNo}        controllers.Application.Put()
```

How will I get the {studentNo} value? For example I'm using a postman(rest client) and I typed something in the url http://localhost:9000/students/2012111222 , how will I get the "2012111222". Do I need to split the URL's value just to get that parameter or is there something else. Thank you.!

Comment: What framework do you use (jersey?) can u provide some more code? A guess: try something like this: `public void myPost(@PathParam("studentNo") studentNo){...some code...}`

Comment: I'm using Play Framework. Sorry If I didn't mention.

Comment: do you have some code? for example for a get method? where this url points to?

Comment: @Override
 public Result getStudents() {

  String[] name = request().queryString().get("firstName");
  

  if (name == null) {

   return ok(Json.toJson(student));

  } else {
   
   return ok("One student with name: " + name);

  }

 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [Play's routing documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaRouting) you can use the colon syntax to define that some part of your route URL is a variable and pass that variable to the controller method, ie:

```
POST  /students/:studentNo        controllers.Application.Post(studentNo: Long)
```

Comment: This would do but my instructor is requiring the one without colon. Is there another way that's similar to something like that?

Comment: @Zelgh What do you mean he is requiring the one without colon? I can't see how this would be a valid Play route since it is not defined in the documentation. Are you perhaps confusing it with the JAX-RS `@Path` annotation which uses curly braces to specify variables in the path?

Comment: Hmmm I don't know. He just gave this notes to follow. 
Example:
2. Update Student
Method: PUT
URL: http://localhost:7777/students//{studentNumber}
RequestBody: Student Info except for Student Number (JSON Format) 
Response: {
 "message": "Successfully Updated Student {Student Number}"
}

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

If you have a string like:

```
String s="POST    /students/12        controllers.Application.Post()";
```

You can retrieve "12" like:

```
int studentNo = Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\s+|,\\s*|\\.\\s*")[1].split("/")[2]);
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, I edited my question. How can I get the URL if it came from a REST client?

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the `/students/:studentNo`, should use `/students?number=111` in POST request and get the value using `DyanamicForm` or `request().getQueryString("number")` without mention the `controllers.Application.Post(studentNo: Long)`

Comment: The fact that you can include the student number as part of the post request body does not mean that you don't also have the option to include it as part of the path.

Comment: I didn't notice. I have edited my post, It should be on PUT not POST.